# What are the differences between the hopping model and the coherence corrected hopping model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, quantum-tunneling

I am trying to understand the difference between the hopping model and the coherence corrected hopping model of electron transport at the molecular level.

I understand that hopping is a process through which electrons "hop" onto and off of bridge sites along the molecule. I also understand that the hopping process is assisted by phonons, which that means it the electrons lose their phase with each hop. I believe I need a more thorough understanding of how the hopping process works and how to relate it back to the Landauer formula for calculating the conductance of a molecule based on the hopping rate.

Moreover, I know there is such a thing as the coherence-corrected hopping model that was raised by Buttiker in the 1988 paper "Coherent and sequential tunneling in series barriers", but I am having trouble understanding how it works, in particular how it corrects for the phase loss.

What is the differences between the hopping model and the coherence-corrected hopping model? Specifically, how does it change the transmission?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This is a really awesome site for physics questions and answers, but for the system to work, we need a question :) There's no question here, so this post is probably going to be closed. Can you edit this post to ask a *specific, focused question*?

Comment: done :) sorry for any confusion

Comment: I edited the text a bit to increase clarity. It's a good question! Are you asking why phonons cause decoherence or what the result of decoherence is on the transmission of electrons?

Comment: I am asking how the coherence corrected model changes the transmission. What exactly is happening to the electrons that allow them to retain phase and why is phase important when transmitting electrons?

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you want to know. Do you want to know 1) Qualitatively why coupling to phonons causes loss of phase coherence, 2) What the transmission rates are in the coherent and incoherent cases, 3) Something else? It's confusing because in your last comment you asked what allows electrons to retain their phase, but that question is nowhere in the main post. If you can focus on something specific I'd be happy to try to answer :)

Comment: maybe it's because i am trying to understand multiple things. not just one. But if you are willing to help i'd appreciate whatever you can do. Yes i do want to understand qualitatively why coupling to phonons causes loss of coherence as well as what the transmission rates are in coherent vs incoherent case.